# Can I Add a Plug to Lights Designed to be Wired In?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

So I purchased [these lights](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0797ZD6B1) on Amazon, not realizing that they don't actually have a wall plug, they're just bare wires.  Can I attach some wiring and a plug to the wires to be able to plugin them into the wall?  If so, what all would I need to accomplish the task?

Here is the only technical information about the lights that I saw: 10W 12V LED Flood Light with Epistar Chip.

And here is a picture of how it is currently wired:

[image: Lights]

Comment: That sounds like an answer isherwood

Comment: Voice of experience, don't buy the *bottom* bottom shelf of those bottom-shelf lights, buy the mid-tier bottom shelf from a reputable (heh) importer.  It makes all the difference in the world.  I bought a no-name generic and also one from an "importer that's been around awhile", the generic died in 3 months, the respectable one is stilll goin... teardown revealed nothing obvious, probably a duff driver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. They're 12VDC, which means if you plug them into your wall they'll go PFFFZZZZZT and make a little puff of smoke. Or worse.

You'll need a power supply (a wall brick) that provides 12 volts and enough current. You can add mating plugs to the lights or just crimp them together.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's **low-voltage** (12V) and ***NOT mains power***, flexible cordage is allowed broadly.

If you missed that it's low-voltage, the dead giveaway is the black and white cord wires in the photo *absent a green/green-yellow equipment safety ground*. Low-voltage DC doesn't need it.

### You'll want to use a plug that is for 12 volts DC

First, **polarity matters**.  Second, the standard 120V NEMA 1 plug *is right out*, because some epsilon-minus will plug it into a wall socket and it will blow up.  I have thought of using sockets like NEMA L3 that are so obscure no one uses them, but conversly, no one sells them either at a sane price.

Honestly, there aren't a lot of good choices for 12 volt DC plug.  The very ungainly "cigarette lighter" socket seems to be the *de-facto* standard, which just goes to show how desperate we are for a standard.  Andersons are also ungainly and Molex are too hard to unplug.  Coaxial connectors like on your Internet router is probably as good as it gets.

If you need outdoor/waterproofing, then hit up electronics supply shops for automotive grade sockets and plugs, with the little gaskets and all that. Or pull 'em off GM cars (the most common) at a u-pull-it junkyard.

Comment: Two pin molex or the battery connectors that remote control car and airplane batteries seem like they'd handle the load and are readily available. They're DC and polarized.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 4 pin XLR connector (generally used for 12V power)

Pinout:
https://www.canford.co.uk/Technical/Article/XLR4PinWiringConvention

10W at 12V is about an amp of current (power divided by voltage) - for safety use 5A cable and use a power supply capable of delivering 15W per lamp attached.

Comment: Could you edit the pinout into the post in case the link breaks?